# Removing virtual COM Ports in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, virtual-serial-port, com0com

I am creating a batch file to remove virtual com ports created before using com0com. at the time of creation, the port names where renamed for example:

```
change CNCA2 portname=COM20
```

So when i want to remove i should use the original name like:

```
remove 2
```

which corresponds to the original portname `CNCA2`

So, what i m trying to do here is if the user chooses to remove Port COM20, how can get the
original name which is `CNCxx` ?

below is the sample of command i used:[image]

as u can see, when i write `remove COM150` there is no change, so i need to get the corresponding name which is `remove 2`.

so from the c# application how can i get the corresponding name without manually using a `list` command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could spawn a command prompt process that runs the list command and capture the output by redirecting stdout to a text file. Then read the results back from the file.

From the example above, it should be relatively simple to parse the results and use them to create a Dictionary, so you can then easily look up the original name given the new name.

Comment: yeah thanks for the suggestion. i managed to save the output of the `list` into a text file. i will try to read it back or make a dictionary. although i ve never a dictionary before.

Comment: You don't need to redirect the output to a file. In .NET the Process class can help you capture the standard output to a stream so you can read it directly.

Comment: @AlvinWong, i didnt know the Process class can capture the standard output, that would be much helpful, let me check it how.